# How to use Google Sheets onEdit() trigger to run function to update Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Sheets workbook in which I have a sheet that I want to use to save settings for both the workbook and a Google Form.

I've made a custom `onEdit()` function which triggers two functions - one to update the workbook, and one to update the form:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;
  if (range.getSheet().getName() == "Settings") {
    setMonthByMonth(); // Updates the workbook
    updateExpenseForm(); // Should update the form
  }
}
```

The workbook function works fine. The form function doesn't. That function looks like this:

```
function updateExpenseForm() {
  var categoryId = "1098744733",
      currencyId = "595880786",
      responsibleId = "2043429480",
      formId = "1arB3yibHa_Y69fc_GxE8mU1FzNR3PYgsivYbrQ0LsQk";

  var form = FormApp.openById(formId);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var settingsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Settings");

  var categoryList = form.getItemById(categoryId).asListItem();
  var responsibleList = form.getItemById(responsibleId).asListItem();
  var currencyList = form.getItemById(currencyId).asListItem();

  var categoryValues = settingsSheet.getRange("A5:A").getValues();
  var categoryNames = [];

  var responsibleValues = settingsSheet.getRange("F5:F").getValues();
  var responsibleNames = [];

  var currencyValues = settingsSheet.getRange("K5:K").getValues();
  var currencyNames = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < categoryValues.length; i++) {
    if(categoryValues[i][0] != "") {
      categoryNames[i] = categoryValues[i][0];
    }
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < responsibleValues.length; i++) {
    if(responsibleValues[i][0] != "") {
      responsibleNames[i] = responsibleValues[i][0];
    }
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < currencyValues.length; i++) {
    if(currencyValues[i][0] != "") {
      currencyNames[i] = currencyValues[i][0];
    }
  }

  categoryList.setChoiceValues(categoryNames);
  responsibleList.setChoiceValues(responsibleNames);
  currencyList.setChoiceValues(currencyNames);
}
```

I can run it manually without any problems from the script editor. But it doesn't run when triggered through the `onEdit()` function. And if I move the form function above the workbook function, the workbook function is not called either.

Am I missing something?

Comment: is this an installable trigger or a simple trigger? maybe an 
Installable trigger will do the trick https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#available_types_of_triggers

Answer (score 3):

It's very likely that you are using a simple trigger. They can't access services that require authorization, like the Forms Service. The solution is to use an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead.

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions

> #### Restrictions
>
> Because simple triggers fire automatically, without asking the user
> for authorization, they are subject to several restrictions:

...

> - They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a
>   simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires
>   authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the
>   Language service, which is anonymous.