# Permission to update form checkbox grid from sheet when the sheet is edited

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to programmatically update the options on a form checkbox grid from a sheet. My code works when I run it in the editor, but not when it is triggered by an edit to the sheet.

I keep getting error 'Exception: You do not have permission to call FormApp.openById. Required permissions: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms'](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms%27).

The form and the sheet are in the same container. I have added permissions to the  appsscript.json:

```
"oauthScopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms"
  
],
```

and my code is in onEdit():

```
var optionsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Options');
var data = optionsSheet.getRange(1,1,optionsSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
var formItems = form.getItems();
var optionItems = formItems.filter(item=>item.getTitle() === 'Options')
optionItems.forEach(item=>item.asCheckboxGridItem().setColumns(data));
```

Can anyone see what I am missing? Why would this work when executed from the editor, but not work when executed by a simple trigger?

Comment: In your situation, how about using the installable OnEdit trigger instead of the simple trigger? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) At that time, please rename the function name from `onEdit` to others. Because when the installable OnEdit trigger is installed to the function `onEdit`, the function is run 2 times with asynchronous process. Please be careful this. And, I thought that this thread might be the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/q/38140933

Comment: Thanks Tanaike! Your solution works, and the thread answered my question about why it doesn't work with a simple trigger.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your replying, I would like to flag your question as the duplicated question of https://stackoverflow.com/q/38140933